# Angular 2 rendering dynamic ngClass

Tags: typescript, user-interface, angular7

```
        <div
            class="day"
            [class.is-event]="hasEvent(events, number, month, year)"
          >
```

After my component`s view has been initialized i'm waiting for this UI behaviour [image]

But for some reason the red dot disappears after several ms, so i could notice that.

```
hasEvent(events: Event[], day: number, month: number, year: number): boolean {
const date = new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
return events.some(
  e =>
    date >= e.startWithoutTime.getTime() &&
    date <= e.endWithoutTime.getTime()
);
```

}

Comment: Is the red dot disappearing because `hasEvent()` is returning false?

Comment: @Collierre the red dot appears only if returning statement is `true`

Comment: Ok so are you sure the problem is not just that the function is returning false?